# Make dplyr::if_else() return a NA value

Tags: r, date, if-statement, dplyr

Using `dplyr::if_else()` on a date, I want to return a `NA` - but there is no `NA_date_` or `NA_double_` in R (that I know of - or listed [here](https://blog.rstudio.com/2016/06/27/dplyr-0-5-0/))? How can I execute the following code:

```
ep <- df %>%
  group_by(id, episode) %>%
  summarise(ep_adm = min(adm, na.rm = T),
            ep_sepa = if_else(all(is.na(sepa)),
                             if_else(all(is.na(adm)), NA, max(adm, na.rm = T)),
                             max(sepa, na.rm = T)))
```

without the error?

> Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) :    Evaluation error: `false`
>   must be type logical, not double.

The motivation for this problem is that rows for each patient id will be classified into an episode of care (the data is coming from different data sources, one of which doesn't include `sepa` dates), which is handled by `group_by()`. I then want to get the episode start and end dates, `ep_adm`, and `ep_sepa`. The rule is that if all the separation dates are `NA` then the last admission date is to be used, other wise use the last separation date.

The code in the expected output works, but I'm looking to remove those last 2 lines of code (using `dplyr::if_else()`, as this *should* return a `<date>` object).

#### Expected output:

```
ep <- df %>%
  group_by(id, episode) %>%
  summarise(ep_adm = min(adm, na.rm = T),
            ep_sepa = ifelse(all(is.na(sepa)),
                             ifelse(all(is.na(adm)), NA, max(adm, na.rm = T)),
                             max(sepa, na.rm = T)))
ep$ep_adm <- as.Date(ep$ep_adm, origin = "1970-01-01")
ep$ep_sepa <- as.Date(ep$ep_sepa, origin = "1970-01-01")

# # A tibble: 4 x 4
# # Groups:   id [?]
#      id episode ep_adm     ep_sepa   
#   <dbl>   <int> <date>     <date>    
# 1     1       1 2002-06-28 2002-07-05
# 2     1       2 2002-08-25 2002-08-25
# 3     1       3 2003-06-26 2003-06-26
# 4     1       4 2007-04-10 2007-04-11

left_join(df, ep, by = c("id", "episode"))

# # A tibble: 8 x 6
#      id episode adm        sepa       ep_adm     ep_sepa   
#   <dbl>   <int> <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>    
# 1     1       1 2002-06-28 NA         2002-06-28 2002-07-05
# 2     1       1 2002-06-28 NA         2002-06-28 2002-07-05
# 3     1       1 2002-06-28 2002-07-05 2002-06-28 2002-07-05
# 4     1       1 2002-06-28 2002-07-05 2002-06-28 2002-07-05
# 5     1       2 2002-08-25 NA         2002-08-25 2002-08-25
# 6     1       3 2003-06-26 NA         2003-06-26 2003-06-26
# 7     1       4 2007-04-10 NA         2007-04-10 2007-04-11
# 8     1       4 2007-04-10 2007-04-11 2007-04-10 2007-04-11
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), episode = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L), adm = structure(c(11866, 11866, 
11866, 11866, 11924, 12229, 13613, 13613), class = "Date"), sepa = structure(c(NA, 
NA, 11873, 11873, NA, NA, NA, 13614), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you please share your expected output?

Comment: Could you explain the rules for adding `ep_sepa`? I'm not quite sure I understand what you're trying to do: For example, `is.na(.$sepa)` checks for `NA` entries across *all* entries in column `sepa`, not within your defined groups. Is that what you want to do? If you could elaborate on the rules, it seems to me that a `case_when` solution might be easier (instead of the nested `if_else`s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

For the updated dataset, seems we can just take `max` Date from `sepa` and `adm` column combined.

```
df %>% 
   group_by(id, episode) %>% 
   summarise(ep_adm = min(adm, na.rm = T), 
             ep_sepa = max(c(sepa, adm), na.rm = TRUE))

#     id episode ep_adm     ep_sepa   
#   <dbl>   <int> <date>     <date>    
#1     1       1 2002-06-28 2002-07-05
#2     1       2 2002-08-25 2002-08-25
#3     1       3 2003-06-26 2003-06-26
#4     1       4 2007-04-10 2007-04-11
```

---

**Original Answer**

If I have understood your code correctly, you can reduce it using `coalesce`. Here for `ep_sepa` column we get first non-NA entry from `max(sepa)` and `max(adm)` column.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
   group_by(rootnum, episode) %>%
   summarise(ep_adm = min(adm, na.rm = T), 
             ep_sepa = coalesce(max(sepa), max(adm)))



#  rootnum episode  ep_adm     ep_sepa   
#    <dbl>   <int> <date>     <date>    
#1       1       1 2002-06-28 2002-06-28
#2       1       2 2002-08-25 2002-08-25
#3       1       3 2003-06-26 2003-06-26
#4       1       4 2007-04-10 2007-04-10
#5       2       2 2012-06-26 2012-06-26
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronak, I found a more complete example data (sorry, I though the other one would have been sufficient). I need to include `na.rm = T` in my min and max, when I add these too your answer I get warnings that I'm trying to eliminate. I've updated my OP to be more complete.

Comment: @Paul  `df %>%
  group_by(id, episode) %>%
  summarise(ep_adm = min(adm, na.rm = T), 
            ep_sepa =  max(c(sepa, adm), na.rm = TRUE))` This seems to give your expected output but I am still not sure if I there are any more cases which I am missing?

Comment: @Paul Moreover, `ifelse` makes `ep_sepa` loose it's class. You can add another command in the chain which you have tried. `df %>%
  group_by(id, episode) %>%
  summarise(ep_adm = min(adm, na.rm = T),
            ep_sepa = ifelse(all(is.na(sepa)),
                             ifelse(all(is.na(adm)), NA, max(adm, na.rm = T)),
                             max(sepa, na.rm = T))) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(ep_sepa), as.Date)` which will convert it to Date class again.

Comment: I think max(c(sepa, adm), na.rm = TRUE) might do it, seems I was over complicating things. I'll test when I'm back at work tomorrow. Thanks for all your help today!